# Text on Left of Arrow in Flow Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, text

I have a flow diagram where text appears on the right of the arrow. I want to shift to the left of the arrow, is that possible?

[image]

```
\begin{center}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
    node distance = 3mm and 2mm,
      start chain = A going below,
       arr/.style = {-Stealth},
every edge/.style = {draw, arr},
        BC/.style = {decorate,  % Brace Calligraphic
                     decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm,
                                 raise=1mm, mirror},
                     very thick, pen colour={black}
                    },
       box/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20, align=center,
                     minimum height=5ex, text width=5.5em},
  decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.5, draw, fill=blue!20,
                    inner xsep=-3pt, minimum width=5.4em, align=center},
    ellip/.style = { ellipse, aspect=1.5,draw, fill=blue!20,
                    inner xsep=-3pt, text width=5.4em, align=center},
                        ]
% nodes in chain
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\node   [box]     {start};         % name=A-1
\node   [box]       {end};

    \end{scope}

 \draw[arr] (A-1.south) -- node{This Text} (A-2.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the text next to the downward pointing arrow appear left of the arrow instead of on the right, you can use `swap`:

From the pgf manual:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
    node distance = 3mm and 2mm,
      start chain = A going below,
       arr/.style = {-Stealth},
every edge/.style = {draw, arr},
        BC/.style = {decorate,  % Brace Calligraphic
                     decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm,
                                 raise=1mm, mirror},
                     very thick, pen colour={black}
                    },
       box/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20, align=center,
                     minimum height=5ex, text width=5.5em},
  decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.5, draw, fill=blue!20,
                    inner xsep=-3pt, minimum width=5.4em, align=center},
    ellip/.style = { ellipse, aspect=1.5,draw, fill=blue!20,
                    inner xsep=-3pt, text width=5.4em, align=center},
                        ]
% nodes in chain
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\node   [box]     {start};         % name=A-1
\node   [box]       {end};

    \end{scope}

 \draw[arr, swap] (A-1.south) -- node{This Text} (A-2.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: works like a charm. Thanks